# Matlab plotting empty window

Tags: matlab, plot

When I try to plot following function, I don't get an error but the plotting window is empty. Can anybody explain why this happens?

```
x = [0:0.1:2*pi];
y = (sin(x)/x);
plot(y.^2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're not doing element wise division, instead MATLAB is doing a matrix psuedo-inverse which results in one value.

Try

```
y = (sin(x)./x);
```

Comment: @gamma Please mark an answer as correct if it solved your question.